# read large data from nonblocking c socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

How can I have nonblocking TCP socket read in C but read the data in large chunks?

In my implementation, the result is always negative and errno is equivalent to "Resource temporarily unavailable" unless we have data larger than 'size'.

```
 result = read(fd, buffer, size);
```

Is it true that when we read a nonblocking TCP socket in C, it will not return >=0 unless it has received the complete data we requested from it?

Comment: The third parameter to `read` is just the maximum number of bytes to read.

Comment: I solved the problem. The call returns correctly if there is no data and I just need to properly check errno. I ask the moderator to close this question

Answer (score 3):

It's not true, it will return `< 0` when there is no data, and it will set `errno` to `EAGAIN` "*Resource Temporarily Unavailable*" or a similar error value. The `read()` function will read as much data as possible and return, the value might be negative indicating an error (*or `EAGAIN` *Resource Temporarily Unavailable* for non blocking socket*) or positive value indicating how many bytes where actualy read.

To check whether there is data to read or not use [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), something like

```
struct timeval timeout = {1, 50000}; // Wait one 1.05 seconds
                                     // or a reasonable value
fd_set rdset;

FD_ZERO(&rdset);
FD_SET(fd, &rdset);

if (select(fd + 1, &rdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 1) // Equals the number
{                                                      // of ready descriptors
    // Read data here
}
// No data ready, now it's your choice what to do
```

Note: On linux, `select()` alters the `timeout` parameter to reflect how much time was left, so you might need to reset it if you call `select()` again with the same parameters.

Comment: EAGAIN is usually interpreted as "Resource temporarily unavailable", so the error he's getting is the expected result when the client didn't end any data.

Answer (score 1):

> the result is always negative and errno is equivalent to "Resource temporarily unavailable" unless we have data larger than 'size'.

Unless there is data present in the socket receive buffer, of any size.

> Is it true that when we read a nonblocking TCP socket in C, it will not return >=0 unless it has received the complete data we requested from it?

No. It will return zero if the end of stream has been reached, or a positive integer if any data is present in the socket receive buffer. Exactly how many bytes triggers this is system-dependent ('low-water mark') but it isn't related to how many bytes you ask for.

However:

- it isn't correct to just keep reading after you've had this condition: you should call `select()` or one of the `poll()/epoll()` methods to tell you when the socket is next ready for reading
- it isn't clear why you're using non-blocking mode at all, if all you have to do is loop and read. I would use blocking mode.

Comment: Why It isn't correct to do so? My program has other things to do meanwhile and instead of poll() I just call this method and if it returns with the right errno, I assume no data is there.